# JSoup parsed elements empty

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jsoup

I am trying to parse some data using JSoup, this is all happening in a asynctask (doInBackground) part of my MainActivity.
Unfortunately all the elements (9) are empty when I execute the app.

When I debug below codeline, I actually get the **complete** website, it`s all there.
The method *readMultipleLinesRespone()* is located in another class *HttpUtility* where I also call my Post and Get requests.

I tested this upfront by saving the website as a file and using JSoups *assets* ability, it worked perfectly then.

The *setupAdapter()* method in **onPostExecute** fills a ExpandableListview with data, should this info be nessecary. If you need more info pls ask.

Can somebody assist and tell me what I am doing wrong?

> response1 = util.readMultipleLinesRespone(); <--- debugged and all data (seems) to be there but isn`t.

**Edit:** If I print response1, there is indeed **no** data to parse. 
Logcat output:

> E/Resonse:: [Ljava.lang.String;@3d3410a

Below is the method readMultipleLinesRespone from HttpUtility class:

> ```
> public String[] readMultipleLinesRespone() throws IOException {
>     InputStream inputStream = null;
>     if (httpConn != null) {
>         inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
>     } else {
>         throw new IOException("Connection is not established.");
>     }
>
>     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
>             inputStream));
>     List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();
>
>     String line = "";
>     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
>         response.add(line);
>     }
>     reader.close();
>
>     return (String[]) response.toArray(new String[0]);
> }
> ```

The asynctask where it`s all hapening:

> ```
> private class FetchWebsiteData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
>     ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onPreExecute() {
>         this.mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
>         mProgressDialog.setMessage("Laden...");
>         mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
>         mProgressDialog.show();
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected Void doInBackground(Void... result) {
>
>         try {
>             util.sendGetRequest("https://mobile.somesite.nl/Data", null);
>             response1 = util.readMultipleLinesRespone();
>         } catch (IOException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>
>         if (response1.length > 0) {
>             Document doc = Jsoup.parse(response1.toString());
>
>             // Get the html document title
>             Elements els = doc.select("span[class=item-value pull-right]");
>
>                 if (els.size() > 0) {
>                     fac_naam = els.get(0).text();
>                     fac_straat = els.get(1).text();
>                     fac_post = els.get(2).text();
>                     con_tel = els.get(3).text();
>                     con_email = els.get(4).text();
>                     betaal_reknr = els.get(5).text();
>                     betaal_houd = els.get(6).text();
>                     zig_gebruiker = els.get(7).text();
>                     zig_wacht = els.get(8).text();
>                 }
>         }
>         return null;
>         }
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
>         super.onPreExecute();
>         setupAdapter();
>         mProgressDialog.dismiss();
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I solved the problem.
I did not pass the response string correctly to the asynctask which parses the required elements.
Just required a public string in which the response is being set and passed (not an elegant way but it works):

```
public static String HttpResponse = "";
```

In the HttpUtility class:

```
public String[] readMultipleLinesRespone() throws IOException {
        ...

        TabFragment1.HttpResponse = response.toString();
     ...
        return (String[]) response.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
```

Then pass it to the asynctask:

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... result) {

            try {
                util.sendGetRequest(LoginActivity.PersData_URL, null);

                util.readMultipleLinesRespone();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (HttpResponse.length() > 0) {
                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(HttpResponse.toString());
                // Get the html document title
                Elements els = doc.select("span[class=item-value pull-right]");
              ...

            }
            return null;
        }
```